# Is there a way we can listen to the click of a checkbox/button but not change its state?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-layout, view

I want to keep the state of a toggle as checked but also get the callback from its clicklistener. How can I achieve it?

```
 binding.toggle.apply {
        isChecked = true
        isClickable = false
        isEnabled = false
    }
```

This helps me keep it checked but I don't get its state in the click listener.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if there is better way to do but you can apply my trick. Create a transparent view(layout, textview,..) cover in front of that checkbox, then set these attribute for it:

```
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

When you click in checkbox, only the cover view get onclicklistener event. When you don't want it anymore, just make it visibility gone!

**Edit**

As you say, you just want to keep state of checkbox

```
     checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
            if(keepCheckState) {
                checkbox.isChecked = isChecked // isChecked is state of checkbox
                //and show your toast
            }
     }
```

Comment: this will require adding an extra view. that will fix this one particular use case but I won't be able to use this in my code bc I can't add an extra view. Also, there is a usecase where I want to be able to off/on toggle as well. my issue is in the second use case where it stays on, but I want to show a message "it can't be clicked" when user pressed it, so it stays checked on.

Comment: @PoojaSingh Got it. Check my edit, hope it help